# FatalThrowableError - Call to a member function getStatusCode() on null

Tags: php, fatal-error

help?

The last time I tested this, it was working but for some reason, when I tested it now, it gives me back this error?

I call my function using this:

```
public function createPayment($uid,$api_uid,$limit)
{
        $api = new CallFunction();
        $result = $api->pay($uid,$api_uid,$limit);
}
```

This is my CallFunction script:

```
 public  function pay(string $userid, string $apiuid, int $limiteos)
    {
       $client = null;

       $api_key = "api_key";
       $url = "http://www.payment.com/payment/order";

        $client = new Client();
        try
        {

            $data = ['method'=>'create', 'user_id' => $userid, 'api_uid' => $apiuid, 'limit_eos_count' => $limiteos, 'api_key' => $api_key];
            $response = $client->post($url, ['query' => $data]);
            $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
            return $result;
           // $this->accessToken = $result->access_token;
        }
        catch (RequestException $e)
        {
           // var_dump($e);
            $response = $this->StatusCodeHandling($e);
            return 0;
          //  echo "error";
        }
    }
```

The error points to this part of the code:

```
$response = $this->StatusCodeHandling($e);
```

My part of my StatusCodeHandling is this:

```
public function StatusCodeHandling($e)
    {
        if ($e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '400')
        {
        $this->prepare_access_token();
        }
        elseif ($e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '422')
        {
    }
```

And error shows me this line:

```
if ($e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '400')
```

Im having a hardtime debugging right now. It was working a few days ago?? Any heads up where I went wrong would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should check that `$e->getResponse()` returns a value rather than assuming it works.

Comment: @NigelRen this returns null, thus the error.

Comment: when ever you get error such as a member function on null, it means the preceding function is returning null, check your functions carefully, maybe try using die function on it to see what it returns

Answer (score 0):

I double checked my link. It turns out, I have a typo in my link that's why it's the request is returning NULL.